# Python: run QGLWidget paint method in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl

For my python program I have a QT user interface which consists mainly of a QGLWidget to display a large number of points (~20 million). The program now runs very unstable, it's hardly possible to resize or move the window.

So I tried to run the `paintGL()` method of the QGL widget in its own thread by using:

```
from thread import start_new_thread

def paintGL(self):
    start_new_thread(paintGLThreading,())

def paintGLThreading(self):
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    <OpenGL paint code>
```

This raises the following exception:

```
#Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method GLWidget.paintGLThreading of <__main__.GLWidget object at 0x00000000043C5F78>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qtWin.py", line 54, in paintGLThreading
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  File "errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src\errorchecker.c:1218)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1282,
        description = 'Der Vorgang ist ung\xfcltig.',
        baseOperation = glClearColor,
        cArguments = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
)
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this right?